# Using latest (GitHub) version of Qiskit as Python library

Tags: programming, qiskit

I just started working in Qiskit and want to use some of the new functions available to Qiskit on Github. Unfortunately, I don't know how to implement the latest GitHub version into my Anaconda distribution of Python.

Anaconda uses an older Qiskit library which I installed using pip. I would now like to git clone the latest version of Qiskit into that location. How can I do this? When I just type `git clone https://github.com/Qiskit` or something similar, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, installing Qiskit through `pip install` will install the latest, stable version of Qiskit onto your environment. So do note, the version you want to clone may not be functional with existing Jupyter Notebooks and other tutorials, since the code is not yet officially released.

That being said, cloning the repo is very easy. The URL that you were trying to clone, `https://github.com/Qiskit`, is the Qiskit Github user account page. That is why you were receiving an error. The repo that you are looking to clone would be [qiskit-terra](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra). Once you are there, you can follow this [article on cloning github repositories](https://help.github.com/en/articles/cloning-a-repository).

Once you have cloned the repo, you can follow this [guide](https://qiskit.org/documentation/install/terra.html#install-terra-source,) on how to install Qiskit Terra from the source code you just cloned.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Today, I also found the following instructions on the Qiskit website, about how to install the developer version of Qiskit via pip install: 
https://qiskit.org/documentation/install/terra.html#install-terra-source